# How do i validate a data URL scheme image

Tags: javascript, php, validation, url-scheme

I made a drag and drop canvas image cropper back in the days and now i need to reuse it in a new project.

Back in the days i used to call **[toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)** send the blob with an Ajax request and handle the file server side with a files class that validates everything, however this time i have to handle it as a normal form post request.

Basically what i do this time around is that i am creating a DOM string with the **[toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)** i then update a input field's value and use that data server side, the data comes formatted and i have to handle the string

Here is a short snippet (part of a larger code base) to show how i create the string and update the input field

```
var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
tempCanvas.width = this.containerWidth;
tempCanvas.height = this.containerHeiht;
tempCtx.drawImage(
        this.ctx.canvas,
        this.cutoutWidth,
        this.cutoutWidth,
        this.containerWidth,
        this.containerWidth,
        0,
        0,
        this.containerWidth,
        this.containerWidth
        );

var dataurl = tempCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
selectElems('cc-upload-blob__input', 'i').value = dataurl;
```

On the serverside i then handle the string like this

```
$picture = $post['cc-upload-blob'];
if (! empty($picture)) {
    if (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $picture, $type)) {
        $picture = substr($picture, strpos($picture, ',') + 1);

        $type = strtolower($type[1]); // jpg, png, gif

        if (! in_array($type, [ 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png' ])) {
            throw new \Exception('invalid image type');
        }
        $picture = str_replace( ' ', '+', $picture );
        $picture = base64_decode($picture);

        if ($picture === false) {
            throw new \Exception('base64_decode failed');
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('did not match data URI with image data');
    }

    $pictureName = 'bla.{$type}';
    $picturePath = '/pictures/'.$pictureName;
    if (file_put_contents($picturePath, $picture)) {
        echo '<h1>Uploaded</h1>';
    } else {
        echo '<h1>Not Uploaded</h1>';
    }
}
```

This demonstration works perfectly fine, it uploads an image, the php scripts strips outs some unnessesary data, get the image type from the string, decode the base64..

My concern is the decoded data? How do i validate this data? I mean is there any security in this? Is it possible to just encode something malicious, append it to a string looking like the normal one? and then the decoded data will be malicious?

I know the data will be fixed with a valid extension from the array before i pass it to **[file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)**, but still? Is there anything to be concerned about? Is there a way i can validate this as i normally would with the $_FILES data and a php upload class?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar project (`<canvas>` -> JS .toDataURL -> Ajax -> PHP ...), I used this logic in the backend to *validate* (at least partially) that the uploaded images were real `PNG`:

```
function checkImage1($image_string) {
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($image_string);
    $valid = ($im != FALSE);
    imagedestroy($im);
    return $valid;
}

function checkImage2($path) {
    if (exif_imagetype($path) != IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        return false;
    }
    //
    return true;
}

// $image (string) is the base64_decoded data from frontend
// $image_path (string) is where the image will be saved

$check1 = $check2 = false;

$check1 = checkImage1($image);
if ($check1) {
   if ( file_put_contents($image_path, $image) ) {
      $check2 = checkImage2($image_path);
      if (!$check2)
        unlink($image_path);
   }
}

if ($check1 && $check2) { /* all good */ } else { /* bad image */}
```

References:

- [imagecreatefromstring](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)
- [exif_imagetype](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.exif-imagetype.php)
- for other types than `IMAGETYPE_PNG`: [Predefined constants IMAGETYPE...](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php)